# How can I close a property window in an application developed with RCP?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I'm having a bit of a trouble modifying an application that I have inherited from another party. The application is a Front End made with Eclipse RCP, and I have to modify one of its property windows so when I click a Save button it will not just save the data to my database, but also close that property window.

I can't find a way to reference the window itself so I can invoke a method like "window.close();", would anyone have a hint by any chance?

Thank you.

Comment: You are going to have to provide a lot more detail as this is far too vague. Are these 'property windows' property pages extending `PropertyPage` or what?

Comment: The class is as follows:  public class SLPropertyPart extends PropertyThreeLevelPart